# Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to Bigquery, but I get the following error:

```
    Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered (bigquery)
```

I've tried the following, but none of this are working:

a) Open the file as save it as "UTF-8" in notepad.

b) Open the file in notepad++ and use the option "Search characters by type" - Non ASCII. Didn't find any character
c) Use notepad++ with the followings regular expressions, didn't find any character:

```
   [^\x00-\x7F] and [^\x1F-\x7F].
```

d) Use the following command:

```
   gsutil cp gs://bucket_987234/compress_file.gz - | gunzip | tr -d '\000' | gsutil cp - gs://bucket_987234/uncompress_and_clean_file
```

**Didn't work: "tr" is not recognized as a command (I'm using windows 10 and I don't have access to a VM of google.)**

d) Open the file and deleted the first row, then it worked. But i've lost a line of data, and I have thousand of files.

The trouble is that I need to automate the "cleaning" of this files.
How can I clean this file in **Windows**, Any idea about what else can this "ASCII 0" character or how to get rid of it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GitBash on your machine? If you can, I would recommend you using this.

```
cat -v filename
```

For example, I have created a file called TESTINGCAT.txt with three lines, which visually has 7 empty spaces. However, if you count spaces with notepad++ you will find just 5 because 2 of those empty spaces are ["non-breaking spaces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) generated by typing ALT + 0160. Below you can see that I have on Notepad++

[image]

However, if I use `cat -v TESTINGCAT.txt` I can see M-BM- characters, which according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357248/how-to-remove-special-m-bm-character-with-sed) are non-breaking spaces

[image]

Therefore, if you do not have access to a Linux machine, you should try using GitBash to see the hidden characters in your file.